# reconstruct image from array javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, raster

How do i reconstruct the image from an array of data in javascript. And display it on my page.

the data is not hex or binary but a color value [0-255] black and white, so 8 bits image.

Could some one give me show direction on how to rebuild the image from such raster data. 
I refer native javascript image object.

here is a simple snippet of the data.

**IMAGE**

```
{"data":[[9,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,9,9,10,9,9,10,9,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,10,9,9,10,9,10,9,9,9,10,9,9,10,9,9,10,9,9,10,9,9,10,10,10,9,10,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,10,10,10,11,10,10,11,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,10,11,10,11,11,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,11,11,12,12,11,12,11,11,11,12,11,11,12,12,12,11,11,12,12,12,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,
```

Each of them represent each pixel.

Thanks

Comment: How can you tell `dimensions` of image from that `data`? i think it is only `color` information, but what about `width` and `height`?

Comment: I do have the dimensions of data array. But it is too large to put it here. my question is about how do you reconstruct it to an image.

Comment: See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-imagedata

Comment: this imageData works with canvas, is there a way to create a generic image object in term of jpeg/png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're providing (albeit incomplete) is extremely similar to the format given by `.getImageData()`. So that is what I've used to create a simple solution.

```
function dataToBase64(colors, width, height){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        color;
    //setup canvas
    canvas.width = width,
    canvas.height = height;
    //grab data
    var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        _data = data.data; //simple speed optimization    
    //place data
    for(var i = 0, l = _data.length; i < l; i+=4){
        color = colors[i/4];
        _data[i] = color,
        _data[i+1] = color,
        _data[i+2] = color,
        _data[i+3] = 255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
    //return base64 string
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Note that this function returns a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string, which you then need to do something with. I've provided a fiddle to show you how to use the function.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evilzebra/9xnn8tw5/)

Answer (score 1):

May Be Something Like 


### `THIS`

and Here is relevant code

JS:

```
var imgData={"data":[100,8,10,12,100,100,14,16,14,100,100,18,18,14,100,0,80,0,80,0,13,15,80,18,0],"width":"5","height":"5"}; // I've added width and height for simplicity
var wid=imgData["width"],hgh=imgData["height"],data=imgData["data"];
function draw(){
var index=-1;
var img=document.getElementById("img");
img.innerHTML="";
for(var i=0;i<hgh;i++)
{
for(var j=0;j<wid;j++)
{
index++;
var pix=data[index];
img.innerHTML+="<span class='pixel' style='background:rgb("+pix+","+pix+","+pix+");position:absolute;top:"+(i*5)+"px;left:"+(j*5)+"px;'></span>"; // rgb(0,0,0)=black to rgb(255,255,255)=white. as your range is also between [0-255];
//change i*5 to i*1 and j*5 to j*1 for 1px X 1px pixel information (I'm using 5X5px).
}
}
}
```

CSS:

```
#img{ 
/* Where You want to draw image */
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
   position:relative;
}
.pixel{ /* pixel dimensions for the image */
    width:5px; /*change to 1px*/
    height:5px; /*change to 1px*/
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="draw();">
<div id="img">
<!-- Here Your Image from given grayscale data will be drawn -->
</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

---

I've observed that if image size incerases 100X100px then the code above hangs UI.
So I've changed it like:

```
 var imgData={"data":[100,8,10,12,100,100,14,16,14,100,100,18,18,14,100,0,80,0,80,0,13,15,80,18,0],"width":"5","height":"5"}; // I've added width and height for simplicity
    var wid=imgData["width"],hgh=imgData["height"],data=imgData["data"];
    function draw(){
    var index=-1;
    var img=document.getElementById("img");
    img.innerHTML="";
    var p=""; /* Note Change */
    for(var i=0;i<hgh;i++)
    {
    for(var j=0;j<wid;j++)
    {
    index++;
    var pix=data[index];
    // Note change:
    p+="<span class='pixel' style='background:rgb("+pix+","+pix+","+pix+");position:absolute;top:"+(i*5)+"px;left:"+(j*5)+"px;'></span>"; // rgb(0,0,0)=black to rgb(255,255,255)=white. as your range is also between [0-255];
    //change i*5 to i*1 and j*5 to j*1 for 1px X 1px pixel information (I'm using 5X5px).
    }
    }
    img.innerHTML=p; /* Note Change */
    }
```

this works fine tested for `255 X 255px`. This should work fine.

---

This code draws a `5X5` dots each of `5px`. To Form a `V` shape in grayscale color.

Hope it helps. cheers :)!!.

Comment: This renders pixel, i am looking for construction of generic object such as a jpeg/png.