# Using innerHTML in loop hangs UI (Sometimes unresponsive page) but the same innerHTML outside the loop doesn't hangs UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was answering a question on SO:

[reconstruct image from array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825636/reconstruct-image-from-array-javascript/26826132#26826132)

In that I come across the strange working of `javascript`.

Suppose we've to add `MXN` (M=Rows, N=Columns) `<div>'s` dynamically,

then we can do it like:

```
var count = 0;

function addTbl(m, n) {
  var div = document.getElementById("tbl_div");
  div.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      count++;
      div.innerHTML += "<div>" + count + "</div>";
    }
  }
}
```

That looks okay, and works fine when M,N are low (say < 50). But when it increases beyond that limit then it hangs UI and makes page unresponsive.

**BUT**

To make it work for higher dimensions I've used:

```
var count = 0;

function addTbl(m, n) {
  var div = document.getElementById("tbl_div");
  div.innerHTML = "";
  var p = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      count++;
      p += "<div>" + count + "</div>";
    }
  }
  div.innerHTML = "" + p + "";
}
```

And it works fine tested up to 250X250.

Why is that?

Does that mean `.innerHTML` is slower? Or anything else?

Hope experts here will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `innerHTML` updates the DOM on each iteration. Using string concatenation, you are updating the DOM only once. Updating the DOM asks some resources to the browser (repaint UI...).

Comment: A. Wolff is completely correct. You should read up on browser reflow.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments in the first example you are updating DOM every cycle. In the second example this happens only once.

So innerHTML is not slower but every time you use it you can think of it as the browser is redrawing the page, using much more resources when done often.